# DB2 trigger send email when new data

Tags: database, triggers, db2

I need to send a notification email when a new entry is added to a user table. This is the first time I am going to be using db2 trigger and I dont have any clear idea on how to combine a trigger and sending email. so I imagine something similar to:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TEST_TRIGGER
     AFTER INSERT ON USER_TABLE
     (here I need to send an email containing the new username which was created)
```

Any help on how to do this properly is much appreciated.

Comment: First suggestion is to include the platform and version/release of DB2. Then, write code to send an e-mail and place it in the body of the trigger. Good techniques for doing that can depend on the DB2 details.

Comment: I already answered you this question in another thread. Do not recreate questions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to write a stored procedure that can handle the email-sending part according to the platform your db2 is running on.
Then you can call this stored procedure with the user name as parameter.

The email-thingie may be something simple like "syscall mail me@mycomp.de new user" or anything more complex.